# Instant Search With Keyup

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('search', '1');

    function OnLoad() {

      // create a tabbed mode search control
      var tabbed = new google.search.SearchControl();

      // create our searchers.  There will now be 3 tabs.
      tabbed.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());

      // draw in tabbed layout mode
      var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();
      drawOptions.setDrawMode(google.search.SearchControl.DRAW_MODE_TABBED);

      // Draw the tabbed view in the content div
      tabbed.draw(document.getElementById("content"), drawOptions);

    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="content">Loading...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi,

If you copy paste the code above you will see google basic search from 
[code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#tabbed_display_mode)

Instead of clicking the search button or enter(submit) to give the results I want the form to submit at keyup, this way it will be like instant search. I tried looking in the files and explored with firebug in every angle but I can't make it work. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You probably don't want it to make a search request every time the user presses a key (if I typed 'bananas' it would make 7 requests, lord knows which order they would come back in either). I'd suggest a countdown timer being set and when it counts down to zero, make the search request with whatever the current value of the search box is. If the user presses a key while the timer is still counting down, reset it to its max and wait again. I'd suggest something like a second or so for this delay. This all means that a request would only be made when the user has actually finished typing.

Comment: you say "You probably don't want it to make a search request every time the user presses a key" actualy that is exactly what I want, something like this:http://demos.9lessons.info/Bing.html. But Bing results realy suck hard:-)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit of a hack, but you could add something like this:

```
1. var inputBox = document.forms[0].search;
2. inputBox.onkeyup = function(){tabbed.execute(inputBox.value);}
```

1. Creates a reference to the input box. In the [code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#tabbed_display_mode) example it is the first form on the page *`forms[0]`* and the input box's name is *`search`* (*`name="search"`*).
2. Will add a function that will run `onkeyup` on the input box. The function will execute the search (*`tabbed.execute`*) passing it the value from the input box (*`inputBox.value`*).

It will cause the search to run when ever the user presses a key. However as [Geoff Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327744/geoff-adams) has stated, doing the search on every key press is really bad practice. If a user is on a slow connection, its going to be wasting bandwidth, you may also find its against Google's TOS to perform so many searches.

You could possibly make the experience a lot better by doing something like this:

```
  1. var wait = 0;
  2. var inputBox = document.forms[0].search;
  3. inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
  4.   clearTimeout (wait);
  5.   wait = setTimeout(function(){
  6.     tabbed.execute(inputBox.value);
  7.   },1000);
  8. }
```

1. Create a holder which will do the search.

   Link to the input box.

   Add a function to run onkeyup.

   Clear any search which maybe waiting to happen.

   Create a timeout passing it a function to run when the timeout occurs.

   Set the function to search passed on the text in the input box.

   Set the timeout for 1 second *(1000 miliseconds)*

   Finished

Now you still have the search onkeyup, but if the user keeps typing, it will forget the last search, so after 1 second of not typing, the search will be performed.

*Try adding the code to the [code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#tabbed_display_mode) after:*

```
// Search!
tabbed.execute("Subaru STI");
```

And clicking **Run Code**.

**Note:** I haven't tested this in anything other than Chrome, IE8 won't even load [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#tabbed_display_mode) for me!!!

---

Typical IE.......

Ok give this a try:

Instead of:

```
var inputBox = document.forms[0].search;
```

Change it to:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementsByName("search")[0];
```

So instead of trying to use the form access, you are actually searching for all elements with the name `search`, this will be an array, so assuming there is only one `search` input, its the first one (*`[0]`*) that you want to access.

---

```
var wait = 0;
var inputBox = document.getElementsByName("search")[0];
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
  clearTimeout (wait);
  wait = setTimeout(function(){
    tabbed.execute(inputBox.value);
  },1000);
}
```

---

OK so I finally got round to having a quick look at [Googles Doc's for the SearchForm](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_class_GSearchForm).

Looks like Google gives DOM access to the input box, instead of relying on the javascript engine to find it, quite simply `tabbed.input` in this case because `tabbed` is the search object. Give this a try *(I'll leave all the above incase its useful to anyone else)*

```
  var wait = 0;
  var inputBox = tabbed.input;
  inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    clearTimeout (wait);
    wait = setTimeout(function(){
      tabbed.execute(inputBox.value);
    },1000);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, again IE8 is not cooperating, aaaarrrgghhhh!!!!!!Why is that thing not dead yet!! It gives me an error(undifined) for 'inputBox'. Since 70% of my visitors are IE users this realy needs to be solved. I hope someone would take the time..I tried everything, but my specialty(so far) is xhtml/css.

Comment: yomoore, take a look at the update, see if that works for you. It looks like IE gets lost when you use the quick access method, so instead use the getElementsByName to search all dom elements for the one you want. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Hi, It still doesn't work. I get an error for the next line(/for inputBox.onkeyup etc) I think your update did work but the problem moved to the next line.

Comment: Hmmm, is there any chance you could share a URL, only I am unable to get the code you posted above working in IE, but if you check out the 'mock up' [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/583Nd/) you will see I have replaced the actual search with an alert, but it does work in IE and chrome. I have updated the answer to give the full block of code to see if that helps. If not what is the actual error you are getting, what message does it give? _IE8 press F12, click on the script tab and reload the page!_

Answer (score 0):

Your 'mock up' is a bit different since it actually has an input field(physical html). In the google code there is no physical html for input. All there is, is div id="content" That might be the problem for IE8. It is the only thing I can imagine..The weird thing is that if I copy all the physical html from firebug(or whatever tool, in between the div content) I can't seem to modify anything... By the way all of the code so far has worked in chrome. And I'm using IE 8.0.6001. This is the error message: 'undefined' is null or not an object  index.html, line 29 character 1 ,witch is: inputBox.onkeyup = function(){

(Oh, somehow I'm not able to comment...)

Comment: By the way I'm using notepad to test. Maybe if I put it online it will work. I can't access my server right now so I have to experiment with this later on.

Comment: Moving on though, tbh I didn't even think of copying and pasting your code into notepad. Now I have, I added the last bit of code from my answer, and it works for me, IE 8.0.7600.16385. Actually Google will create the HTML for you - hit F12 in IE, on the HTML tab, press the refresh icon, you will see the HTML that google has injected into the DIV content for you.

Comment: Take a look at the update to the answer - I took a look at Google's doc's and found they give access to the input box. See if that one works.

Comment: YES IT FINALLY WORKS!! AWESOME!! I truly appreciate your time and effort. Thank you so much. By the way, this is the website I whant to use it for:vynora.com I'm now using the Bing results which to me don't make any sense. Agian thank you verry much.

Comment: No problem at all yomoore, glad to have helped out. I took a look at your link, if I'd seen the jQuery tag on your question (didn't see jQuery in your original code, hence going with javascript) it would have been a little easier because it takes care of cross browser differences, still nice little challenge!! If you want the code you are using on your page now explaining let me know, is that your email in the contact at the bottom of the page - if you want the code explaining that is!?

Comment: Hi @Scoobler,I don't understand what you mean with "If you want the code you are using on your page now explaining" Do you mean the Jquery version..?If so,than yes please (of course).The contact email at the bottom is indeed my email.Sorry i didn't mention Jquery.(I don't now why I didn't..)I actually do have one more question tho; If I understand you and  @Geoff Adams correctly then you guys are telling me that I'm only allowed (by Google) a certain amount of queries.But aren't you guys by any change be talking about the old version?: http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#gen12

Comment: I asked someone about it: http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/7a2a3fb2e83951f6